# trimming MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I would like to trim an existing MySQL ISAM table, 10million records.

What would be a SQL statement to delete the last 5million records?  This is just a log table, no damage done by removing records.

Comment: How do you determine which records are "last"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from table where id >= (select * from (select id from table order by id limit 4999999,1) as t )
```

Comment: Guys, how would i link these 2 then?

    SELECT id,DeviceReportedTime FROM SystemEvents WHERE ID < ( select * from (select ID from SystemEvents order by ID limit 10,1) as t );
    select MAX(ID) from SystemEvents;

Answer (score 1):

You can use ORDER BY and LIMIT with [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) to affect only a limited number of rows. The way that you would get the 'last' 5 million depends on what you have as far as determining record age, and use that in your ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *
FROM ???` (youre table name)`ORDER BY`?????? `LIMIT 5000000`

Here ??? = youre table name, and ?????? is the way you sort youre table. So if you have some sort of date or number of entry to sort by. 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

I've used SELECT in my example above so you can try out first if it works correctly! If it does work, change SELECT into DELETE :)
If it doesn't work, than you've to try something else to sort by :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this works

```
DELETE FROM tableA ORDER BY some_indexed_column DESC LIMIT 1000000
```